# How import and export components (functions) in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to export and import components in my project, but i don't getting.

My code of the my main App:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Search from './Search';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const peoples =[{id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
    {id:1, name:"Jaquinha"}, 
    {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
    {id:3, name:"JaCA"}, 
    {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
    {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
    {id:6, name:"Da iIIane"}, 
    {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
    {id:8, name:"Tamyresss"},
    {id:9, name:"Tamyres"}, 
    {id:10, name:"Abeu"}, 
    {id:11, name:"Abellll"}];
    
    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage:3,
      currentPage:0,
      peoples,
      input: "",
      filtered: peoples,
    };
    
  } 
  
  getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
    this.filterNames(inputValue);
  }
  
  filterNames = (inputValue) => {
    const { peoples } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      filtered: peoples.filter(item => 
        item.name.includes(inputValue)),
        currentPage:0
      });
}
```

And i want to import functions for other file, called `Search`, functions: `getValueInput`and `filterNames` and after to import for my `render()`:

```js
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Search/>
  </div>
 )
```

The page, `Search.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {App} from './App'

export class Search extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        
    }
    
    getValueInput = (evt) => {
        const inputValue = evt.target.value;
        this.setState({ input: inputValue });
        this.filterNames(inputValue);
    }
    
    filterNames = (inputValue) => {
        const { peoples } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            filtered: peoples.filter(item => 
                item.name.includes(inputValue)),
                currentPage:0
            });
        }
        
        render (){
            return(
                
                <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
                <ul>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()}</ul>
                
                </div>
            )
            
        }
    }
    
    export default Search;
```

But giving error in page `Search.js` and not works:

> Line 1:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
>     Line 2:  'App' is defined but never used        no-unused-vars

*I want to have the same functionality but with separates files.*

Someone would can help-me?

Comment: Those aren't errors...that's your linter telling you that you have Component and App variables that you're not using anywhere.

Comment: But giving that and not working, i would want to export that functions and to import in other file for stay more clean the App.js

Comment: Have you tested the ```export default``` for the component ?
Also you can use ```callback function``` for using the functions which are used in the other components.

Comment: @salman.zare
How would do it?

Comment: export default class Search or import {Search} from './Search'

Comment: @RickLee but how i will to use the functions of the `app.js`? I dont can, giving error :(

Comment: I don't get it. Where is the state in your Search.js? How will you use those functions there? Why are you importing Search in your App.js and again importing App in your Search.js? Something weird here. Do you want common functions and use them various components? If so, then use a file for that, ie. helpers.js, and export your functions. Whereever you want import and use them.

Comment: @devserkan I want to separate the components of my project, understand?
For example, I wanted to get the `getValueInput` and `filterNames` function and create a separate file called 'Filter.js'. It is

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the same function in two different files, it's better to put that function into a separate file and export/import into both `App.js` and `Search.js`.

Generally, the functions within a `class` or `Component` are intended to be used within that class.  That is one of the benefits of classes as it allows functions to stay a bit more "private".

Here is one way to approach it:

**filters.js**

```
// Here I am creating separate functions not tied to either
// class and exporting them from the file.

const getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
    this.filterNames(inputValue);
}

const filterNames = (inputValue) => {
    const { peoples } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        filtered: peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes(inputValue)),
        currentPage: 0
    });
}

export default { getValueInput, filterNames };
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Search from './Search';

// Import the function.
import { getValueInput, filterNames } from './path/filters';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        const peoples = [
            {id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
            {id:1, name:"Jaquinha"}, 
            {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
            {id:3, name:"JaCA"}, 
            {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
            {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
            {id:6, name:"Da iIIane"}, 
            {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
            {id:8, name:"Tamyresss"},
            {id:9, name:"Tamyres"}, 
            {id:10, name:"Abeu"}, 
            {id:11, name:"Abellll"}
        ];

        this.state = {
            elementsPerPage: 3,
            currentPage: 0,
            peoples,
            input: "",
            filtered: peoples,
        };

        // Bind the functions to the class.
        this.getValueInput = getValueInput.bind(this);
        this.filterNames = filterNames.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.getValueInput} className="someInput" />
                <Search />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Search.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import the functions.
import { getValueInput, filterNames } from './path/filters';

export class Search extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        const peoples = [
            // ...
        ]

        this.state = {
            elementsPerPage: 3,
            currentPage: 0,
            peoples,
            input: "",
            filtered: peoples,
        };

        // Bind the functions to the class.
        this.getValueInput = getValueInput.bind(this);
        this.filterNames = filterNames.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return( 
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
                <ul>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()}</ul>
            </div>
        )       
    }
}

export default Search;
```

---

With this approach your code will stay 'DRY' and you can use the function within each class.  You do need to make sure the state in each class has the appropriate values as well.

**EDIT:** Also, see the comment below for how to get rid of the warning you are receiving.

Comment: All good but remove the import of "App" to Search. Either remove Component from import or extend Component instead of React.Component (same thing of course, but it will get rid of the warnings)